# Compare new txt file with old txt file and remove all data that matches

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a new file with the following data separated by a carriage return

```
a
a
b
c
d
d
```

I have an old file that is also separated by a carriage return

```
b
d
```

How do I remove b & d from the new file and remove one of the a's from the first file?

The desired output, separated by a carriage return, would be

```
a
c
```

I have tried sort -u which removes the b & d but also removes the a a.
I have tried grep -vxFf however, there are duplicates from the new file.

Comment: Look into the `uniq` command to remove duplicates

Comment: I did that with the `sort -u (uniq)` and it removes the a and a. I would like one of the a's to stay. It'd be better if there was a merge command maybe?

Comment: You say "remove one of the a's". Does that mean if there are 3 a's, the result should have 2 of them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 grep -F -f oldfile -v newfile | uniq
```

Use the oldfile as search for grep, in the end remove duplicate lines.

Comment: Thank you!! that worked :) I really appreciate it.

Comment: If this worked for your, then please show your appreciation by "accepting" it: click the checkmark next to the answer. This also shows other users of this site that a usefull answer is available here. Feel free also to upvote other answers with different approaches that also work.

Comment: `grep -F -f oldfile -v newfile | sort | uniq` will guarantee the unique results.

Comment: Thank you @dedunu. I will add the sort and test it out. I appreciate all of the replies.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dedunumax/38fc581d337df9b442f4bffce3960492 https://www.onlinegdb.com/LNJSGfsFB this might help!

Answer (score 7):

Using `awk`, print only the lines of `newfile` that haven't previously occurred in either file:

```
awk '!(seen[$0]++ || NR==FNR)' oldfile newfile
```

Comment: Thank you @steeldriver. Is this better than the grep I am using? I'll try it, but I am happy grep.

Comment: @RobertCarroll it's not necessarily *better*, but it is subtly *different* from the [currently accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1474183/178692) in that it will remove duplicates wherever they occur, without sorting, whereas `grep ... | uniq` will only remove *adjacent* duplicates, while `grep ... | sort | uniq` will remove all duplicates but may result in re-ordered output. So it depends what you want.

Answer (score 3):

If you can sort the files (which I assume as you said you tried `sort -u`), you can run `comm oldfile.sorted newfile.sorted` which will show the contents in three columns - old file only, new file only, both files. The `-1`, `-2`, `-3` options allow you to suppress some of the columns, so `comm -13 oldfile.sorted newfile.sorted | uniq` should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Read `man grep` and do something like:

```
grep -F -f oldfile -v newfile
```

Comment: That doesnt work either. I still have the issue of a and a both being on the updatedFile. `grep -vxFf oldfile newfile > updatedFile` produced the same result.

Answer (score 1):

In [`perl`](https://perldoc.perl.org/):

```perl
perl -ne 'print if ! ( $seen{$_}++ || $#ARGV eq 0 )' oldfile newfile
```

Or:

```perl
perl -ne '( $seen{$_}++ || $#ARGV eq 0 ) || print' oldfile newfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **comm**:

```
comm -1 -2 <(sort -u old) <(sort -u new)
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the `grep` answer works for you, `sort` and `uniq` can do the trick also.

Assuming you have the construct `<(command)` available (e.g. use bash).
The construct will be replaced by a temporary file, containing the output of `command`.

This will work, with your example:

```
sort <(uniq new) old | uniq -u
```

Though more general would be:

```
sort <(uniq new) old old | uniq -u
```

Which also works if the `old` file contains lines that are not in `new`.

What happens is, that first the `new` file gets it duplicate lines removed. (This assumes that duplicates in the `new` file are adjacent. Otherwise replace `<(uniq new)` by `<(sort -u new)`.)

Then the output of `sort ...` is taken as input to `uniq -u`.

`uniq -u` prints lines that are occurring only once.

Because the `old` file is presented twice to the `sort ...` command, none of the lines in `old` will make it to the output of `uniq -u`.

Also any lines common between `old` and `new` will not be present.

---

---

`sort` and `uniq` can be combined in several ways to perform mathematical set operations:

1. Set union: f U g

   **sort f g | uniq**
2. Set intersection: f ∩ g

   **sort f g | uniq -d** ## `uniq -d` only prints duplicate lines
3. Set difference: f \ g

   **sort f g g | uniq -u** ## `uniq -u` only prints unique lines

Note that the files `f` and `g` represent sets. So they must not have duplicate lines. If that is not the case, replace e.g. `f` by `<(sort -u f)`.